# Issue storing a variable in a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a problem, I'm storing a variable in session using a servlet, but when I try to get that same variable on another servlet I get this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Here's the servlet where I store the info:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String appointmentId = request.getParameter("selectEditPatientAppointment");

    System.out.println(appointmentId);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("appointmentToEdit", appointmentId);

    response.sendRedirect("doctorEditAppointmentForm.jsp");
}
```

And here's the one where I try to get the variable and I get the error:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Date date = convertStringToDate(request.getParameter("appointmentDate"));
    String time = request.getParameter("appointmentTime");
    String doctorId = request.getParameter("selectEditDoctor");
    String patientId = request.getParameter("selectEditPatient");
    String description = request.getParameter("description");
    String results = request.getParameter("results");
    String test = request.getParameter("appointmentToEdit");

    System.out.println("Esto: " + test);
    int appointmentId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("appointmentToEdit"));

    ListService service = new ListService();
    Doctor doctor = service.getDoctor(doctorId);
    Patient patient = service.getPatient(patientId);
    Set patientappointmentses = new HashSet(patient.getPatientrecord().getPatientappointmentses());
    Patientrecord patientRecord = new Patientrecord(patient,patientappointmentses);
    patientRecord.setPatientRecordId(patientId);

    RegisterService registerService = new RegisterService();
    registerService.patientRecordExists(patientRecord);

    PatientappointmentsId patientappointmentsId = new PatientappointmentsId(appointmentId,patientId);

    Patientappointments patientAppointments = new Patientappointments(patientappointmentsId,doctor,patientRecord,date,time,description,results);


   try {
        EditService editService = new EditService();
        editService.edit(patientAppointments, patientappointmentsId);
        response.sendRedirect("doctorAppointmentEdited.jsp");
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The variable name is `appointmentToEdit` and when I print to console I get the info correctly on the first servlet.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

the `variable` you stored in the session

so

you should get the variable by this way

```
 request.getSession().getAttribute("appointmentToEdit")
```

hope this helped

Comment: @Andres if that solves the issue, consider marking this as the accepted answer: there's a checkbox that you can tick, giving recognition and reputation to Javy who helped you quickly and correctly.